# JasperReports group by all - display row even if nothing returned

Tags: group-by, jasper-reports

I am trying to get JasperReports to mimic the SQL `GROUP BY ALL` functionality.  I am grouping by `MY_BOOL` which can either by 0 or 1 and I am displaying the value, and a count on the number of rows in my report.  However, I want to display a row for each, even if there are 0 rows for one of the values.  So for example, if my query returns ten rows, and `MY_BOOL=0` for all ten, I would like to see:

```
MY_BOOL | COUNT
0         10
1         0
```

How can I accomplish this in JasperReports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:
It sounds like you need 2 variables and no groups.

$V{MY_BOOL_0} counts all rows where $F{MY_BOOL} is 0. $V{MY_BOOL_1} counts all rows where $F{MY_BOOL} is 1. The initial value of each variable is 0, so it doesn't matter if there are zero rows with $F{MY_BOOL} = 0.

Display the 2 variables in the title (or summary or wherever) to provide your 2 "grouped" subtotals.

Note: These 2 variables don't use groups at all, but they would be compatible with groups. For example, you could calculate the MY_BOOL_0 and MY_BOOL_1 values for each month if you group on months.

Comment: How will that work then within the GROUP, if there are still 0 entries with MY_BOOL=0, how will I get a row to appear?  Or do I need to abandon the GROUP to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I see how you're looking at it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this though.  As it stands, I have my rows organized by group (MY_BOOL).  The group functionality really is exactly what I need.  Doing it the way you propose will work well in a simple example, but in my real application I have 22 fields which are being summed up etc based on the group they are in.  To get it to work in a regular band, I think I would need to make a strange looking query to grab data based on the MY_BOOL value.  Ideally, I would like to keep it as is, and only add an extra row if the count of MY_BOOL=0 or MY_BOOL=1 is 0

Comment: Is your data in a relational database? Can you push the grouping down there?

Comment: It is relational, I guess I'll just need to do everything with variables and forget about the group band.  Thank you